# Prestashop cookies lost/hidden on product page

Tags: php, cookies, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, missing-cookies

i have a problem with cookies.

I moved my Prestashop installation from one hosting to another. Everything is working fine, except one: when i enter any product page the cart is empty and there is no user logged in.
When i enter any other url (except product page), all items in cart are in the same configuration like they were before i enter product page and the user is still logged in.

But it looks to work fine, when i load the product page with some post data! This post data is sending by my custom module.

This module allow users to choose between displaying prices with or without tax. When user enter my shop for the first time he have to choose one option. Then he is pressing a button, that submit form with selected option. My module store his option in cookies and never display popup again. On every page its working (the popup is not showing), because on every page there are cookies available.

When i enter product page, the popup is displaying again, and i can see, the cart is empty and there is no user logged in, like it was without my module.

But when i choose one of my module options and submit form, the product page is reloading with all cookies - all cart items, logged user and stored option from my module.

When i hit refresh and resend post data, it still work, but when i enter product url without refresh(resend post data) there is no cookie again.

This problem is not related with my module, because i was trying with and without it, and on the old hosting it was working good.

Can You help me with this?

Comment: Have the same problem, no solution yet. Tried wiping caches and regenerating `.htaccess` as per forum advice - no luck yet. Tracked it down to `initContent()` somehow wiping `logged` variable from Smarty, while `is_logged` variable is still there. Maybe it's creating another instance of Smarty engine or something.